# Using grep -f when the file with patterns contains dots

Tags: linux, grep

If I want to search for a string which contains a dot, in command line I can just prepend it with a backslash:

```
grep "string\." file.txt
```

or add `-F -r` parameters:

```
grep -F -r "string." file.txt
```

but there seems to be a problem if I want to use `grep -f` and have strings with dots inside the file with patterns.

I tried using quotes, prepending all the dots in the file with a backslash and using `grep -F -r -f` and even messed a bit with `-E` but none of these match the strings correctly without interpreting the dots as special characters.

How to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `\` before `.`:

```
grep -f  <(sed 's/\./\\./g' file_with_dots_inside.txt)  file.txt
```